# Windows 8.1 Flash Debugging on Google Chrome

Tags: windows, flash, google-chrome, debugging, trace

I have a Flash game (written in Haxe with Sublime Text 3) that I am trying to debug in the browser. It doesn't matter which browser - I just need to be able to see the trace statements and exceptions thrown.

I've tried a tool like vizzy and it just keeps telling me that I don't have a Flash debugger. I've tried to disable the default one and install one from the Adobe but it never appears on the plugins page of chrome.

I installed the 8.1 Flash update but it does nothing for me in terms of viewing trace statements. The `flashlog.txt` file is empty and I've set the variables in the `mm.cfg` file.

I'm at my wits end. Anyone have a workaround for this or maybe some open source tool to view the trace statements?

Comment: Does it have to be on google chrome? Can you debug it in the flash editor?  Otherwise you can also expose a global function call to javascript instead of using trace you would use the javascript function which would then call `console.log('with your output');`